# How to execute ajax into block view

Tags: 7, ajax

I'm in Drupal 7. I would like to execute an ajax function in my front-page. I've defined the block view in my ".module" file. When I change the selected option, the log gets two errors:

1.

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'test_services_search_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 842 of /var/www/html/test/html/includes/form.inc).

2.

> Notice: Undefined index: test_services_search_form in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 807 of /var/www/html/test/html/includes/form.inc).

#### `test.module`

```
function test_services_block_info() {
  $blocks['test_services_search_form'] = [
    'info' => t('Plan your trip'),
  ];
  return $blocks;
}

function test_services_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = [];
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'test_services_search_form':
      module_load_include('inc', 'test_services', 'includes/test');
      $form             = drupal_get_form('test_services_search_form');
      $block['content'] = render($form);
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

#### `test.inc`

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * TEST - File search inc.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_form().
 */
function test_services_search_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['search'] = [
    '#type' => 'container',
  ];

  // Transfer.
  $form['search']['transfer'] = [
    '#ajax'       => [
      'callback' => 'test_services_search_transfer_callback',
    ],
    '#attributes' => [
      'class'    => ['js-select2', 'cancel'],
      'required' => TRUE,
    ],
    '#title'      => t('Transfer'),
    '#options'    => [
      0 => t('Direct trip'),
      1 => t('Stopover trip'),
    ],
    '#type'       => 'select',
  ];

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Callback handler for the direct/transfer trip select.
 */
function test_services_search_transfer_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

/**
 * Callback function.
 */
function test_services_search_form_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  return $form;
}
```

The point is disable three fields if option two is selected, It's possible execute AJAX into a block view, and if so, what is going on? Why Drupal is not going into the function of the AJAX callback?

Comment: The code from test.inc needs to be in test.module. This will fix error 1 and may also fix error 2

Comment: I'm gonna try it, but i'm calling test.inc with "module_load_include" in my block view hook, it should works anyways.

Comment: Ok. You are right, i don't understand how, but it works. So I can not split the form code in other file?

Comment: Yes it possible, but your module_load_include call is incorrect, I believe from you oiriginally posted it should be module_load_include('inc', 'test', 'test'), take a look at https://api.drupal.org/module_load_include

Comment: Are you sure? $type (inc) | $module_name (test_services) | $path_to_file (includes/test). I mean, that's the way i was trying to execute ajax, but only works if the form is in the ".module" idk why.

Comment: No I'm not sure, but what you've posted in your last comment is not the same as your initial post. I would suspect you've got different names as the module and the files which is why it's not working. I suggest removing all reference to test as it's confusing, try using foo instead as it's obvious and easily replaceable

Comment: Yes, It's a little messy. I've changed the original proyect name to "test" and it's unclear, but file/module names are ok, they are being called. The only problem is that if the form and ajax call are in test.inc instead of ".module", it fails.

Answer (score 0):

> I've defined the block view. When I change the selected option, the log gets two errors.

It seems the error happens after you submitting the block. So the file loads fine on view, but not when the form is processed which should have information where to look for it.

So you should define your form using [`hook_forms`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_forms/7.x).

> By default, when `drupal_get_form()` is called, the system will look for a function with the same name as the form ID, and use that function to build the form. If no such function is found, Drupal calls this hook.

Also, when you working with the forms, instead of [`drupal_get_form($form_id)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7.x), you can consider using `form_load_include()` to make sure the include file is loaded whenever the form is processed.

> Use this function instead of `module_load_include()` from inside a form constructor or any form processing logic as it ensures that the include file is loaded whenever the form is processed. In contrast to using `module_load_include()` directly, `form_load_include()` makes sure the include file is correctly loaded also if the form is cached.